# Magento 2.2.7 error when using bulk attribute update when item is enabled

Tags: magento2, attributes

When trying to use the **bulk update attributes** I get the following error:

> Exception message: Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

I've been chasing this error for the last 2 weeks.  At one point the function worked fine but now it doesn't.

I finally found out when you **disable the item** you can use the **bulk attribute** update and it works fine.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Rich

Comment: show us the payload and the endpoint you're sending it to